# OS X Yosemite: System slow and using a lot of RAM

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, memory

I noticed that my OS X sometimes goes very laggy and it does everything slowly. I opened up Activity Monitor and I saw that it's using a lot of memory.

Any ideas on how to fix this (because I guess it should't be using 3.98 GB out of 4 GB + 1.75 GB of *swap* memory)?

[image]
[image]

I'm using mid 2012 MacBook Pro.

Comment: WindowsServer is using 11 GB and relatively lots of CPU. When did you last reboot your MBP? If you reboot, does the problem occur again immediately or only after you start specific applications (running both Steam and several Chrome tabs might put some load on the system here)?

Comment: @patrix my MBP wasn't rebooted for like 2-3 days I think. Anyways, I just rebooted it and it seemed to fix the problem. What still bothers me is that memory used is still 3.98GB. Is it normal (swap used is 0 Bytes and Virtual memory is 4GB)? And why did rebooting help?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comment it had probably something to do with the WindowServer.

---

Now regarding the other part of the question:

OS X presents memory usage in a different way when comparing to say MS Windows.
For example, if you quit an app in OS X, its memory is available to other apps, but it is not 'cleared' (so if you relaunch the app it would be quite faster in most cases).

My MBP is currently showing 7.88 GB ("Memory used" our of 8GB total), but everything runs as smooth as after restarting (Memory pressure is minimal).

I suggest you read the [How to use Activity Monitor](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201464), especially the section about [Memory](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201464#memory), where you can find some additional information.

Long story short, you better check the "Memory Pressure" indication graph in order to have a more accurate idea about your system's current status.