# What is the "typical" (WindowServer) O/S (CPU/MEMORY/THREAD) usage per "display" (1920 x 1080) by the process?

Tags: performance

Whats the "typical" CPU/MEMORY/THREAD usage per "display window" by the O/S process (WindowServer)?

I'm seeing the following ...

**WindowsServer Usage Statistics:**

Average CPU Load: 10%
Memory: 193.0 MB
Threads: 11

[image: (WindowServer)]

So the main quesiton I'm asking is "how much CPU + MEMORY" load should I expect per additional (1920 x 1080) display?

Thanks!
Asher

Comment: I’m not sure what a display window is, but window server does nothing until a program wants to draw content. This doesn’t seem to be a general question that people could apply since each person does different things with their Mac and loads different software.

Comment: There is no typical "CPU/MEMORY/THREAD" because what you do with your Mac is entirely different from what the rest of us do.  The Apps we use are entirely different and how they utilize memory and CPU as well as threading will vary widely.  This is the 3rd or 4th question where you're looking for this "magical value" that simply doesn't exist and you've yet to articulate why it's important and what exactly you're trying to answer/solve.

Comment: not true?  there are several examples of "average load" metrics already used by apple.  For example, the memory footprint or thread count per process..? of course this changes depending on the specifics but its "nice to know" a vague average for example.. .most processes on the system spawn "on average" about 3 to 3.5 threads... (on my system) its a helpful number to "know" in my opinion... ;)

Comment: Upvoted, because its memory consumption is definitely a function of a displays and their resolution (among other variables). If it's hard to measure, it doesn't mean that some benchmark cases cannot be measured, e.g. "on OS version X and hardware Y, after login, on an empty screen, it takes approximately Z. After opening https://twitter.com/stackoverflow and scrolling 100 records, it becomes A".
It's surely not normal if it takes 11Gb memory, for example: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169917/os-x-yosemite-system-slow-and-using-a-lot-of-ram/169937#169937

Answer (score 4):

There is no such typical cpu/memory/threads "usage" per connected display.

As a quick test you can watch the values in Activity Monitor and then plug in a few displays to your computer, and then unplug them one by one again. You'll see that there's no fixed value that the usage jumps by. Nor is there going to be on a longer term.

All in all the memory usage by WindowServer depends on what each and every GUI application on your computer is actively doing - it is going to be very different over time.

Answer (score 2):

The WindowServer responds to the demands of the user and OS to display all the graphical content on the screen.  Its CPU and memory allocation will change depending on how many windows and dialogs you have open. Scrolling, or otherwise animating the display, will increase the load briefly.

The values you show are 'not untypical', certainly.